# Retrieve a complete list of installed packages

Tags: package-management

I am completely reinstalling kubuntu to my machine since gnome crashed occasionally for its long standing bugs.

How could retrieve a list of all the packages I have ever apt installed and install them to a fresh kubuntu system with one command line?

Comment: Kubuntu uses KDE, yet you mention GNOME crashed?  Gnome is pretty stable but has issues with extensions designed for different releases of gnome (ie. abi breakage) but these shouldn't impact a KDE/Qt based Kubuntu.  `dpkg -l` will all list packages installed, but you can re-install using 'something-else' without formatting your partitions, your added packages are noted, system directories are wiped & installed done, then software on your system is added back (if from known Ubuntu repos); without a single command.  Have you considered that option for re-install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to list installed packages

```
dpkg -l
# or
dpkg-query -f '${binary:Package}\n' -W
# or
dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall
# or
apt list --installed
```

Now, you want to save the list of installed packages and use the list with a fresh install.
 - Save the installed packages list to a file
 - Launch an `apt install` command feeded with the file

```
# SourcePC : Save a list of installed packages
dpkg-query -f '${binary:Package}\n' -W > /path/to/installList.txt

# TargetPC : Prepare, Install, Clean
# -- Prepare
sudo apt update 
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
# -- Install packages list from file
sudo apt install $(< /path/to/installList.txt)
# -- Clean: Fix eventually broken dependencies and remove unnecessary
sudo apt -f install
sudo apt autoremove
```